# How to modify / delete restricted project?

Tags: phabricator

Accidentally removed myself (administrative-level user) from a project and I am unable to access/modify it. Is there a way to unlock the project?

I have control and access of the server to execute and back-end commands.

Answer (score 2):

`bin/policy unlock PHID-xxxx` from the command-line.

Comment: I'd like to add that `bin/policy unlock` also works by passing the project name. For example: `bin/policy unlock #my_fancy_project`